# Django Creating Dynamic Form, with queryset's values as field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Let say I have a queryset with 3 records. What i want to create a form using this queryset and use the value of a field(say name field of model) as the field name of form. And there must be as many fields are many there are records in that queryset. 
Please HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically add fields in form. Say  you have a model `MyModel` with `name` field.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

You can define form with dynamic fields like this

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = kwargs.pop('qs')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for instance in qs:
            self.fields[instance.name] = forms.CharField() # or whatever field you want
```

You can use this form with queryset

```
qs = MyModel.objects.all()

form = MyForm(qs=qs)
```

Comment: but this is forcing the request to GET every time instead of POST, and that where I am stuck